# QR decomposition results in Python (using numpy) and in C++ (using Eigen) are different?

Tags: python, c++, math, eigen, qr-decomposition

**Sample QR decomposition Code (Python):**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the 2D array
data = np.array([
    [12, -51, 4],
    [6, 167, -68],
    [-4, 24, -41],
    [-1, 1, 0],
    [2, 0, 3]
], dtype=float)  # specify data type as 'float' to match C++ double




q, r = np.linalg.qr(data)
print(q)
print(r)
```

**Sample QR-Decomposition C++ code (Eigen):**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

void qrDecomposition(const Eigen::MatrixXd& A, Eigen::MatrixXd& Q, Eigen::MatrixXd& R) {
    int nRows = A.rows();
    int nCols = A.cols();

    Q = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(nRows, nCols);
    R = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(nCols, nCols);

    Eigen::MatrixXd v(nRows, nCols);
    Eigen::MatrixXd u(nRows, nCols);

    for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++) {
        v.col(j) = A.col(j);
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            R(i, j) = Q.col(i).dot(A.col(j));
            v.col(j) -= R(i, j) * Q.col(i);
        }
        R(j, j) = v.col(j).norm();
        Q.col(j) = v.col(j) / R(j, j);
    }
}

int main() {
    int nRows = 5;  // Number of rows
    int nCols = 3;  // Number of columns

    // Sample flattened array (replace with your data)
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> A_data(new double[nRows * nCols], nRows, nCols);
    A_data <<
        12, -51, 4,
        6, 167, -68,
        -4, 24, -41,
        -1, 1, 0,
        2, 0, 3;

    Eigen::MatrixXd Q, R;

    qrDecomposition(A_data, Q, R);

    std::cout << "Matrix Q:\n" << Q << "\n";
    std::cout << "Matrix R:\n" << R << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**RESULTS:**

**python results:**

```
q
array([[-0.84641474,  0.39129081, -0.34312406],
       [-0.42320737, -0.90408727,  0.02927016],
       [ 0.28213825, -0.17042055, -0.93285599],
       [ 0.07053456, -0.01404065,  0.00109937],
       [-0.14106912,  0.01665551,  0.10577161]])
r
array([[ -14.17744688,  -20.66662654,   13.4015667 ],
       [   0.        , -175.04253925,   70.08030664],
       [   0.        ,    0.        ,   35.20154302]])
```

**c++ results:**

```
Matrix Q:
  0.846415  -0.391291  -0.343124
  0.423207   0.904087  0.0292702
 -0.282138   0.170421  -0.932856
-0.0705346  0.0140407 0.00109937
  0.141069 -0.0166555   0.105772
  
Matrix R:
 14.1774  20.6666 -13.4016
       0  175.043 -70.0803
       0        0  35.2015
```

**PROBLEM:** As can be seen in the results above, the signs of the values are different (**not always flipped**). Why is it so?

Comment: QR decompositions are not necessarily unique. I think you will find that if you multiply Q and R, you get the same result in both cases. (Of course, your own decomposition code could also be faulty.)

Comment: The main difference, and you don't need to know what QR decomposition is, is that you have a hand-made version in C++, while the python version uses a library routine.  Can you guarantee that what you wrote in C++ is what the python library is call is doing?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I understand the maths of QR decomposition, and that if we multiply Q and R then, we will get the original matrix A. I tried different input matrices and the signs are always different. On C++ side, I used hand-written code (using Gram-Schmidt projection) and also used Eigen library but the signs are always different to that of the Python generated results. I am wondering what's the difference in the logic which results this difference.

Comment: @skm Numpy uses LAPACK's decomposition, which is not Gram-Schmidt (G-S is numerically unstable and thus not suitable for computers). There can be several decompositions; see e.g. [here](https://www.math.purdue.edu/~kkloste/cs515fa14/qr-uniqueness.pdf) about uniqueness theorems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making the assumption that `numpy` is using Gram-Schmidt.  The [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.qr.html) suggests that is not always the case.  They mention Householder, Gram-Schmidt and least squares.  The source code is available [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.0/numpy/linalg/linalg.py) if you want to see what they actually do.  You can use `eigen` to directly solve the problem with their Householder method and you will see that `eigen` and `numpy` return the same values.

```
   Eigen::Matrix<double, 5, 3> data;
   data << 12,-51,4,6,167,-68,-4,24,-41,-1,1,0,2,0,3;

   auto QR = data.householderQr();  //auto may not be efficient here...
   Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> Q1 = QR.householderQ();
   Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> R1 = QR.matrixQR().triangularView<Eigen::Upper>();

    std::cout << Q1 << "\n\n" << R1 << "\n\n" << Q1 * R1 << std::endl;
```

The output is:

```
 -0.846415   0.391291  -0.343124  0.0661374 -0.0914621
 -0.423207  -0.904087  0.0292702  0.0173785 -0.0486104
  0.282138  -0.170421  -0.932856  -0.021942   0.143712
 0.0705346 -0.0140407 0.00109937   0.997401 0.00429488
 -0.141069  0.0166555   0.105772 0.00585613   0.984175

-14.1774 -20.6666  13.4016
       0 -175.043  70.0803
       0        0  35.2015      
       0        0        0      
       0        0        0      

        12        -51          4
         6        167        -68
        -4         24        -41
        -1          1 4.3715e-16
         2          0          3
```

You'll of course notice that `eigen` returns the full Q matrix which can be thinned by a 5x3 identity matrix.  If you implement householder I think you'll find that it will match `numpy` in this case.